# MoviePY can't detect ImageMagick binary on Windows

Tags: python, imagemagick, moviepy

I just got myself a new laptop, wanted to setup `MoviePY` on that new `Windows 64x` `(Python3.7.0)` machine. I triple checked everything but when it comes to text part of my code, it throws that error at me;

```
OSError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:

OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

"ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect"
```

My `config_defaults.py` file;

```
import os
FFMPEG_BINARY = os.getenv('FFMPEG_BINARY', 'ffmpeg-imageio')
#IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = os.getenv('IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY', 'auto-detect')
IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\magick.exe"
```

The path is correct and both `magick.exe` and `convert.exe` exist in that path. I'm also sure `ImageMagick` is properly installed. When I type convert in `cmd`, it prints `"ImageMagick 7.0.8 Q16 x64"` and bunch of other stuff.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try uninstalling ImageMagick-7, and install ImageMagick-6.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same error as you but my problem was that I did not properly installed ImageMagick : in the installation wizard you need to check "install legacy utilities".

So I reinstalled it, checked this box and it worked.

Here is a screenshot of the page I am talking about : [image]

Comment: 38 MB, here is the download link https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php

Answer (score 6):

Take the comment from the top line, and instead of `auto-detect` put the path and put the name `convert`.

```
IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = os.getenv ('IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY', 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\convert.exe')
```

Comment: for windows users, you might not find the `convert.exe`file. instead just use `magick.exe`.

 `IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = os.getenv('IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY', 'C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\magick.exe')`

Comment: This works. If you are using jupyter notebook, restart your kernel.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and it got fixed thanks to this [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/moviepy/comments/98sazz/comment/ebusacu/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

```py
from moviepy.config import change_settings
change_settings({"IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY": r"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\\magick.exe"})
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Elegant! Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For windows users,

Change line 54 in config_defaults.py wherever moviepy library is installed

It can be in `C:/users/anaconda/lib/site-packages` if you are using anaconda

```
IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = os.getenv('IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY', 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.11-Q16-HDRI\magick.exe')
```

will work